# Fiddler send request to remote server to localhost instead

Tags: fiddler

This seems like a very simple thing in Fiddler, but anything I try to search returns a bunch of completely irrelevant subject matter on localhost URL rewriting.

---

**The ask:**

I have a request to `https://www.example.com/somestuff`

I need any request to `example.com` to instead call that same URL in `localhost`, i.e. `http://localhost:12345/somestuff`

I do **NOT** need a redirect. I need my browser to think I'm calling a remote server, but get a response back from my local server for debugging a thing that looks like it came from the remote server.

---

**Attempts:**

*I have tried*`regex:https://www.example.com/(.*)$` -> `http://localhost:60876/$1` in AutoResponder and enabled rules, but this doesn't appear to give me what I want though the tester tells me it does match my actual request.

The local server response to this request is set to a test value that never shows, the remote server response is retrieved every time. I am able to get the desired response by hitting the local server URL directly, so it is configured correctly from that perspective.

*I also tried* adding this in the FiddlerScript inside `OnBeforeRequest`:

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("www.example.com")) {
    oSession.hostname="localhost";
    oSession.port="12345";
    oSession.oRequest.headers.UriScheme = "http";
}
```

Which just gives me a "stalled" response I am unfamiliar with.

Edit: the above FiddlerScript gives me this when attempting to access my remote server directly: `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` in Chrome, so that's getting somewhere.

I don't use fiddler often and this is well outside my normal development, so hold my hand like you're teaching a toddler.